# C# enforcing a 'single frame' object pool

Tags: c#

```
/// <summary>
/// A pool of short-lived items of the same type.    
///     
/// Items taken from the pool have a lifetime of one frame, after which they are automatically
/// returned to the pool. 
/// 
/// You should NOT hold references to items fetched from this pool across frame bounderies
/// however it is impossible for this class to enforce it...
/// </summary>
public class FramePool<T>
{
    public delegate T Create();
    public readonly Create HandleCreate;

    public delegate void Reset(ref T item);
    public readonly Reset HandleReset;

    private readonly List<T> _in;
    private readonly List<T> _out;

    public FramePool(int initialCapacity, Create createMethod, Reset resetMethod)
    {
        HandleCreate = createMethod;
        HandleReset = resetMethod;

        _in = new List<T>(initialCapacity);            
        for (var i = 0; i < initialCapacity; i++)
        {
            _in.Add(HandleCreate());
        }

        _out = new List<T>();
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        if (_in.Count == 0)
        {
            _in.Add(HandleCreate());
        }

        var item = _in.PopLast();
        _out.Add(item);

        return item;
    }

    public void EndOfFrame()
    {
        _in.AddRange(_out);
        _out.Clear();
    }
}
```

So there are a couple types of 'object pools'.

There's the standard type where the code which calls `var obj = pool.Get()` also needs to call `Return(obj)` when it is done.

And then there are pools like I have here, which get around that by having a 'return everything' method which gets called at some regular point in your program.

Now this isn't the *safest* class in the world, as it has no way to enforce that callers stop using objects on frame boundaries. Which is ok... ***but perhaps someone can think of a clever way, in C#, to implement a single-frame object pool that CAN enforce the 'correct' usage and/or detect 'incorrect' usage.***

Comment: You're asking how to create a garbage collector from scratch, so you can avoid using the built in garbage collector.  Hence your question makes no sense.  The garbage collector *is a pool of objects* that is responsible for ensuring that objects are reclaimed after they're no longer in use.  That's what you're asking for.  It comes at a cost, if you don't want to keep track of it yourself.  That's inherent in the problem.  You can't get all of the benefits of a GC at zero cost, else that'd just be how the GC would be made in the first place.

Comment: I suspect there are degrees of 'enforcement' to the reccomended usage which are possible in less extreme ways than implementing your own reference counting. Nevertheless, even in that case, sometimes thats exactly what you want to do. Because doing your own 'garbage collection' on a subset of objects to which it is appropriate rather than everything (which will be triggered if you allocate 100 of these small objects) is a performance win.

Comment: You seem to overrestimate the actual costs of the GC.  It's far more sophisticated than you seem to think.  First off, it doesn't use reference counting at all, it does a sweep algorithm instead.  Next, it has several "generations" that get collected separately, so that creating a lot of cheap objects quickly and frequently doesn't add costs to longer lived objects, providing the exact behavior that you're trying to emulate.  Once again, you're basically trying to re-create behaviors *that the garbage collector is already using for you*.  Let it do its job.

Comment: I know how GC works and its irrelevant to this discussion, the reason i even mentioned reference counting is because implementing a 'gc-like' system within this class would certaintly not use anything as sophisticated as generation passes.

Comment: And that would almost certainly result in it performing worse than the GC, precisely because it *wouldn't* be as sophisticated.  That's why I'm telling you that you should just use the GC.

Comment: There is no reason for any GC to be occuring at all, when i use 100 objects of a fixed type every frame, and reuse them the next. Thats the point of a pool, and they exist because ZERO GC cost is better than ANY GC cost. Do you feel like posting an actual answer to the actual question now?

Comment: Sure, the GC costs go from something to nothing, and the non-GC work that you do goes form nothing to even more than the work the GC would have done.  The actual amount of work done, and the time it would take the program to execute, would go *up*, not down, as a result of this change.